# how to match multiple patterns and change one part with sed

Tags: sed

I have the below lines in a file:

```
SUT_INST_PIT=true
SUT_INST_TICS=true
SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=false
SUT_INST_PING=false
```

How can i create a sed line to match pattern `SUT_INST_EXAMPLES` & `SUT_INST_PING` and set `false` to `true`?

I can't simply replace `false` with `true` because I don't want to change `SUT_INST_PIT` & `SUT_INST_TICS` even if they are false!!!

I have at the moment two `sed` commands that are working, but i would like one line only!

```
sed -i "s/SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=false/SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=true/g" <file>
sed -i "s/SUT_INST_PING=false/SUT_INST_PING=true/g" <file>
```

One more thing the `sed` line should be able to be parametrized to set `false`->`true` or `true`->`false`, but only for `SUT_INST_EXAMPLES` & `SUT_INST_PING`.

Solution (according to @RomanPerekhrest) and how to use it in send (expect script):

```
send "sed -i 's\/^\\(SUT_INST_EXAMPLES\\|SUT_INST_PING\\)=false\/\\1=true\/' file\r"
```

Comment: How to exclude comments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -i 's/^\(SUT_INST_EXAMPLES\|SUT_INST_PING\)=false/\1=true/' file
```

---

`file` contents:

```
SUT_INST_PIT=true
SUT_INST_TICS=true
SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=true
SUT_INST_PING=true
```

---

`\(SUT_INST_EXAMPLES\|SUT_INST_PING\)` - alternation group, matches either `SUT_INST_EXAMPLES` OR `SUT_INST_PING` at the start of the string

---

Alternative ***gawk***(*GNU awk*) approach:

```
gawk -i inplace -F'=' -v OFS='=' '$1~/^SUT_INST_(EXAMPLES|PING)/{$2=($2=="false")? "true":"false"}1' file
```

Comment: I am trying to use the sed line from your answer in a expect send command but it is failing:  `SUT:/home # =true/' file -i 's/^(SUT_INST_EXAMPLES|SUT_INST_PING)=false/`  `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token SUT_INST_EXAMPLES`

Comment: Updated Question with solution according to @RomanPerekhrest.

Comment: Thanks worked nicely. I wanted to Replace all 
`<MyNode>string</MyNode>`
with 
`<MyNode>stringMyNode</MyNode>`

And this is what I used
`sed -i 's/string<\/\(.*\)>/string\1<\/\1>/' try.xml`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply toggle with:

```
sed -i -E '/^SUT_INST_(PING|EXAMPLES)=/{s/false/true/;t;s/true/false/;}' infile
```

This will change `true` to `false` or `false` to `true` depending on the current value.

Answer (score 4):

`sed` allows you to do multiple operations on each line:

```
sed -e '...' -e '...' file
```

So you can at least combine your two `sed` invocations into one with

```
sed -i -e 's/^SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=false/SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=true/' \
       -e 's/^SUT_INST_PING=false/SUT_INST_PING=true/' file
```

To parametrize the replacement, use variables:

```
examples="true"
ping="false"

sed -i -e "s/^SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=.*\$/SUT_INST_EXAMPLES=$examples/" \
       -e "s/^SUT_INST_PING=.*\$/SUT_INST_PING=$ping/" file
```

The above will unconditionally set the values of `SUT_INST_EXAMPLES` and `SUT_INST_EXAMPLES` to that of `$examples` and `$ping` respectively.