# How to match a pattern and substitute only part of the pattern?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have the below single long line in a file:

```
#cat file
5LkoVZg0BABCBkD9OieAflA==|list1|true|0|0|0|172661|1.16|186042, 5o0QEZg0BABCA3j9OieAflA==|list2|false|0|0|0|0|0|0, 5F3NnwwoBABC1Dfrsf9xucw==|list3|false|0|0|0|0|0|0, 5FaJmwwoBABC0-frsf9xucw==|...
```

I would like to replace the comma character with a new line, so the output looks like this:

```
 5LkoVZg0BABCBkD9OieAflA==|list1|true|0|0|0|172661|1.16|186042
 5o0QEZg0BABCA3j9OieAflA==|list2|false|0|0|0|0|0|
 5F3NnwwoBABC1Dfrsf9xucw==|list3|false|0|0|0|0|0|0
 5FaJmwwoBABC0-frsf9xucw==|...
```

More specifically the comma positioned before the " 5" character, note there is a space always before the "5" character.

I can replace the comma simply using:

```
#cat file | sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g'
```

However this is not good enough because the comma can be located sometimes also in other awkward positions like below:

```
#cat file
5LkoVZg0BABCBkD9OieAflA==|list1 , |true|0|0|0|172661|1.16|186042, 5o0QEZg0BABCA3j9OieAflA==...
```

I prefer using sed but other solutions would be great too.
I have searched internet four couple of hours but could not find a solution for my exact problem.

Comment: similar, although not quite what is my requirement:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363940/how-to-match-multiple-patterns-and-change-one-part-with-sed

Comment: if it's always `, 5` (comma,space,five) then replace just that: `s/, 5/\n 5/g` ?

Comment: @ilkkachu, thx that works too. However using solution in answer is more robust and really captures my intention to use \S*== (5LkoVZg0BABCBkD9OieAflA==) as leading sequence for a new line.

Comment: Please note that `\n` in the replacement string will not work with some implementations of `sed`, as the beheviour is not POSIX specified.

Answer (score 4):

***sed*** approach:

```
cat file
5LkoVZg0BABCBkD9OieAflA==|list1 , |true|0|0|0|172661|1.16|186042, 5o0QEZg0BABCA3j9OieAflA==|list2|false|0|0|0|0|0|0, 5F3NnwwoBABC1Dfrsf9xucw==|list3|false|0|0|0|0|0|0, 5FaJmwwoBABC0-frsf9xucw==|...
```

---

```
sed 's/, \(\S*==\)/\n\1/g' file
```

The output:

```
5LkoVZg0BABCBkD9OieAflA==|list1 , |true|0|0|0|172661|1.16|186042
5o0QEZg0BABCA3j9OieAflA==|list2|false|0|0|0|0|0|0
5F3NnwwoBABC1Dfrsf9xucw==|list3|false|0|0|0|0|0|0
5FaJmwwoBABC0-frsf9xucw==|...
```

---

`\S*==` - sequence of non-whitespace characters followed by `==`, treated as leading sequence of each line

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This works great, as soon as I build my rep will vote.

Comment: @Kalfa, you have my upvote for your question

Answer (score 0):

A more simple solution by using `tr` as following:

```
cat file | tr "," "\n"
```

Where `tr` will look for comma `,` and replace it by new line `\n`

Output:

```
5LkoVZg0BABCBkD9OieAflA==|list1|true|0|0|0|172661|1.16|186042
 5o0QEZg0BABCA3j9OieAflA==|list2|false|0|0|0|0|0|0
 5F3NnwwoBABC1Dfrsf9xucw==|list3|false|0|0|0|0|0|0
 5FaJmwwoBABC0-frsf9xucw==|...
```

Noting that the spaces before the comma were kept.